# Extract and Display a webpage using javascript / greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

The easiest way i can think to explain this is to tell you exactly what im trying to do! -

(A little background first though. Im wanting to be able to learn how the following works so i can use it on many future projects. What im trying to accomplish today is the one and only reason im wanting to work with Javascript / Greasemonkey.)

My objective: To show parts or a whole website within another website. I would like to be able to insert parts of one webpage into another.. Example: Facebook - On the home page (logged in), the right hand side above 'People you may know': i would like to be able to show content from a group im a member of.

Ive tried many google searches to try and find some form of tutorial/wiki on this but have come to no avail.

If you can / are willing to help, an answer would be great but with wanting to use this in different projects to do with different websites, i would rather be able to learn exactly how everything works.. So maybe a complete explanation or even pointing in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, was there by mistake. Have removed the tag!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this using greasemonkey, but I would recommend using iframes for this purpose. See Mozilla's documentation on iframes for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe

Another approach could be to use javascript talking to a webserver to fetch the html you want to display on the server side (using PHP, python, etc) and return down only the parts you want to display. The javascript could then insert that chunk of html into the browser and voila, your desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast reply. IFrames wont work with facebook though as i cant edit their pages :(